# List the names and row numbers of missing data in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

I was wondering how to list the names and row numbers of missing data in a data.frame in R?

**An example as well as the desired output are below:**

```
DF <- data.frame(X = c(1, 3, NA, 2), Y = c(NA, NA, 5, 4), Z = 4:7)

var.names <- names(which(colSums(is.na(DF)) > 0)) # names of the variables with missing

row.index <- which(rowSums(is.na(DF)) > 0)  # row number of the variables with missing

# Desired output:

list(X = 3, Y = c(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply` automatically loops over columns, returning a list with an item for each column:

```
lapply(DF, function(x) which(is.na(x)))
# $X
# [1] 3
# 
# $Y
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $Z
# integer(0)
```

Comment: You can filter out empty elements easily enough.

Comment: `which` does exactly what you want. I don't know of any faster version of `which`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use also use `split`

```
with(as.data.frame(which(is.na(DF), arr.ind = TRUE)), split(row, names(DF)[col]))
#$X
#[1] 3

#$Y
#[1] 1 2
```

Comment: Hi Arun, I think this data.frame [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805298/loop-over-a-subbseting-logic-on-an-r-data-frame) is a difficult one.